# Change QTableWidget default selection color, and make it semi transparent

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I am trying to change the default color for selection in a QTableWidget, but I need to make it transparent so that I can still see the color of the underlying cell.

I used :

```
self.setStyleSheet("QTableView{ selection-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 50);  }")
self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
```

So now the selection color is kind of red, but some cells are defined as:

```
cell.setBackgroundColor(color)
...
self.setItem(i, j, cell)
```

And still the color of the cell is overwritten by the selection color (no mixing, just the pink-red selection). I tried setting a foreground color for the cells instead of background color :

```
brush = QBrush(color, Qt.SolidPattern)
cell.setForeground(brush)
```

but it does not change anything.
So is there a simple way to do it, or should I handle the selection by hand ?
(redraw the selected row with my own colors)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use **only** stylesheet with `QTableWidget::item{ background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 50%); }` to set normal cell color and 
`QTableWidget::item:selected{ background-color: rgba(20, 0, 0, 50%) }` to set selected cell color

Comment: If I use `QTableWidget::item` to set the background color, it will be the same for each cell, right ? The problem is that we set color differently for each cell we repurposed the widget to display a trivalued matrix so the colors are all that matters

Comment: You are right, so from what I understood, you need a different color for each cell but the selected color, it needs to be the same for each cell with some transparency (in your case red), then try to apply your stylesheet on your `QTableWidget` with only `QTableWidget::item:selected{ background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 50%) }`

Comment: I've tried using only the line you gave me (BTW is there a difference between this one and `QTableView{ selection-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 50);` ) but the result is ultimately the same [Visual](http://imgur.com/a/Q5eCN). Also the selection does not have to be red or even a color: if a can circle the whole row it's ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had almost same scenario, but insetead i have text in cells and i wanted fully-transparent selection (so no change to background color)
if you set transparent color, it will be solid (bug in qt?) so i set text to be BOLD (= selected) and turn of selection-style
here the code, maybe it would help

```cpp
//.h
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
class SelectionControlDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    public:
        SelectionControlDelegate(QObject* parent = 0);
        void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem* option, const QModelIndex& index) const override;
};

//.cpp
SelectionControlDelegate::SelectionControlDelegate(QObject* parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

void SelectionControlDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem* option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
    const bool selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
    option->font.setBold(selected); // this will represent selected state
    if (selected)
    {
        option->state = option->state & ~QStyle::State_Selected; // this will block selection-style = no highlight
    }
}

// in widget class
...
_ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(new SelectionControlDelegate(this));
...


// when setting cell background, i would change also text color 
QColor textColor = backgroundColor.value() <= 120 ? Qt::white : Qt::black;  // if it is dark, text would be white otherwise black
// or you can compute invert color...
```

here is my visualization: 5% and 25% items are selected

selection presentation

[image]