# Selection highlight in PyQt4 QTableWidget fill selected cell's background with full block color

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am working on a small PyQt4 task manager. A similar question is ask in here [Change QTableWidget default selection color, and make it semi transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226768/change-qtablewidget-default-selection-color-and-make-it-semi-transparent) . From this post, I try to setStyleSheet for selection background color opacity, but the highlight is still override the cell background color. Is there someone can help me show how to change this to border color?

Image below is my current result

[image]

This is what I willing to achieve, as you see, the highlight selectionis just overlay the background color, but not override it.

[image]

At the end, hopefully my question is clear enough for everyone, if found any unclear or mistake, please kindly let me know, I will fix as fast as possible!
Thanks!

Comment: I recommend improving your question, the links are referential and secondary, Describe what you want and place what you have tried.

Comment: My question is updated, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Did you work my answer?

Comment: Hello [![name][1]][1] , thanks for your reply. I try to run the script, but not sure why its come out this error.
(line 25, in paint
    if option.widget:
AttributeError: 'QStyleOptionViewItem' object has no attribute 'widget')

The only thing i add is import the module.
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
import sys

    [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc

Comment: I think it is a problem of versions of pyqt4, I have updated the code, please check it again

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc , thanks for your reply again! But I only can test the script in my office later. I will report to you again else I test it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, tell me about any problems you have.

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc , I tried the script and now the result is like this https://i.imgur.com/JWNC4Pm.jpg[/img] (test by maya python),  https://i.imgur.com/7ccJhT8.jpg[/img] (test by default python idle) . As the result, the data in tablewidget now is hidden, I only can see through the data by double click on cell. Is it possible because of PyQt4 bug?

Comment: It seems strange, in my case did not give me that behavior, I improved the code please test it again, you could also share the test you have done in IDLE.

Comment: Hi, @eyllanesc  Now, the data is appear after execute in default python IDLE. But when I select the cell, the selection is override the number https://i.imgur.com/BEvSOru.jpg[/img]. For Maya python, I only can try when I go to office later. Thank you!

Comment: Please share the code you use.

Comment: I have already improved the code, try again please

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc, a simplified version code is added above. 

This is latest result I test, https://i.imgur.com/bI9mExm.jpg[/img] . The selection highlight still override cell background color. But what I expect is something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lssjQ.jpg .Thanks!

Comment: comments the lines that use the setBackground function, the above is to verify if the cause of the problem is that and then to publish a solution for that particular case.

Comment: Yo, @eyllanesc, after I test your script again, I realize that the color of row actually is changed! (Previously the alternate row color is not contrast, so I miss to see the different.) But after I change alternate row color to more contrast, I can see it very clearly. I think I already know the concept you show to me, I will apply to my code later. Very glad-full for your help and seriously thank for your precious time!

Comment: try with this code, I could correct some more things https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/fc53a05025dedb979905a21c7cc8ce3f

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc,  the script in GitHub is fully suit for my situation. I also get some knowledge other than my questio. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Of course, I forget to update my answer with the new code, now I will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to change the colors is to use a delegate.

For this we must get the current background color, the task of getting the background color is tedious since a QTableWidget has its own color as its background, it also has the colors that you add to QTableWidgets and other types of elements so my answer currently has limited support but the idea is scalable.

The color to be displayed as the background of the selected element is an average of the background color and a color chosen properly, in this case we choose the color **#cbedff**

I have implemented all of the above in the following class:

```
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        class StyleDelegateForQTableWidget(QStyledItemDelegate):
            color_default = QColor("#aaedff")

            def paint(self, painter, option, index):
                if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
                    option.palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
                    color = self.combineColors(self.color_default, self.background(option, index))
                    option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, color)
                QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

            def background(self, option, index):
                item = self.parent().itemFromIndex(index)
                if item:
                    if item.background() != QBrush():
                        return item.background().color()
                if self.parent().alternatingRowColors():
                    if index.row() % 2 == 1:
                        return option.palette.color(QPalette.AlternateBase)
                return option.palette.color(QPalette.Base)

            @staticmethod
            def combineColors(c1, c2):
                c3 = QColor()
                c3.setRed((c1.red() + c2.red()) / 2)
                c3.setGreen((c1.green() + c2.green()) / 2)
                c3.setBlue((c1.blue() + c2.blue()) / 2)

                return c3

        self.setItemDelegate(StyleDelegateForQTableWidget(self))
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TableWidget()
    w.setColumnCount(10)
    w.setRowCount(10)
    for i in range(w.rowCount()):
        for j in range(w.columnCount()):
            w.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem("{}".format(i * j)))
            if i < 8 and j < 8:
                color = QColor(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256)
                w.item(i, j).setBackground(color)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Deselected:**

[image]

**Selected:**

[image]